# How to move div to the foreground when there are sticky elements?

Tags: html, position, z-index, sticky

I have a header with an absolutely positioned element (imagine that this is a dropdown). After that I have a big table with data and sticky header.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="panel">
  <div class="dropdown">

  </div>
</div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <-- data -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

css:

```
.panel {
  background: yellow;
  height: 40px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1000;
}

table {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}

thead th {
  background: orange;
  position: sticky;
  top: 40px;
}
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/sh90fo4k/1/

Why I am unable to overlap table header with dropdown?

Comment: When I added a z-index for the .panel it works: https://jsfiddle.net/xt9zfso1/1/ but it doesn't make sense why it isn't working without this hack

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="x">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="dropdown">

      </div>
    </div>
    <table >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>A</th>
          <th>B</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
        <td>A1</td>
        <td>A52</td>
      </tr>    
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```
.x{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
.panel {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}


.dropdown {

  left: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1000;
}

table {
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}

thead th {
  background: orange;
}
```

Comment: if that help you??